# Convert xml to docx document

Tags: java, xml, converters

My goal is to convert an XML document to docx, to make it a more human readable. At the moment I am in a research phase and trying to locate some libraries which provide this type of functionality. I found the following ones if there is any other which are easier to use please suggest.

[Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/index.html)
[Docx4J](http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j)

Comment: Sadly, SO questions asking for a library recommendation tend to be closed as being subjective. Best approach is to try this library and come back to SO if you hit problems.